# Copy from excel and paste into online form

Tags: excel, web, copy, paste

Firstly may I apologise for the fact that I am not the best with computers,

I have quite a large excel sheet for which I have to copy and paste 10 columns per row into an online form.

Is it possible to create a macro for this and if yes how can I do so.

Also please keep in mind that I am at work, so I'm limited from the use of plugins and I unfortunately have to use internet explorer.

Your help would be much adored,

Thank You

Comment: For example - http://www.excely.com/excel-vba/ie-automation.shtml. Plenty more on google if you search "VBA automate IE"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You can use IE to automate this using vba.

```
Sub xtremeExcel()
  Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
  Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
  sURL = "*******Paste URL Here************"
  Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer
  oBrowser.Silent = True
  oBrowser.navigate sURL
  oBrowser.Visible = True
  Do
  Loop Until oBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
  Set HTMLDoc = oBrowser.document
 'Use firebug to identify the textbox or object you need. and you can set its value like 
 'HTMLDoc.GetElementByID("abcd").value="xyz"

End Sub
```